# Using an virtual/abstract class to define an common API for a pipeline architecture

Tags: c++, plugins, abstract-class, pipeline

I'd like to create a pipeline architecture constructed of plugins that ingest a variety of data types and can produce a variety of data types that would then be fed to any plugin connected to it. Since templated abstract functions aren't a thing, I figured what ever base class I used would need to define send and receive functions for all possible types. Child classes would then define receive functions for data types they are interested in, process the content, then send the newly generated data on to a vector of base classes via their receive functions. By default, the base class would just return on data types it hasn't specialized a receive function for, thus not doing anything (I understand there is probably unnecessary overhead here).

I failed to recall that calling a base's virtual function will invoke said base's version of the virtual function unless defined as pure virtual or the object I'm actually handling was that of the child. But since connected plugins would be stored in a vector of base plugins, all I would have had access to is the base's receive function. Turning the base's receive method into a pure virtual method would elevate the call to the child's receive method but that would mean I need to implement the entire possible interface for each plugin. Is there an easier way to doing this?

More general, is this a good approach to what I'm trying to do? This plugin pipeline would ideally be dynamic and created on demand so connecting plugins together in such a fashion seemed to be the right way to go. And it needs to be quick. If iterating over connected plugins to push data even when some plugins don't do anything with the data is slow, I can cache the data before pushing the reference on so I only iterate through the plugins once.

Guess this boils down to, is there a design architecture out there that allows for convenient communication between classes that supports a varying amount of transferable data types.

```
#define ADD_TYPE(type) \
    inline void send(const routing::route_t route, const type& data) { for(auto &plugin : m_registered_plugins) plugin->receive(route, data); } \
    virtual inline void receive(const routing::route_t& route, const type& data) { return; }
        // Thought about trying this second -->
        // virtual inline void receive(const routing::route_t& route, const type& data) = 0; 

class PluginBase
{
public:

    PluginBase(const std::string& name) 
        : m_uuid(m_uuid_gen())
        , m_log(name)
    { }

    virtual ~PluginBase() { }

    bool pluginIsDescendant(PluginBase* plugin) const
    {
        for (auto registered : m_registered_plugins)
        {
            // Did we find the plugin
            if (registered == plugin)
                return true;

            // Is the plugin a descendant of this
            if (registered->pluginIsDescendant(plugin))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool connect(PluginBase* plugin)
    {
        // Don't connect to self
        if (plugin == this)
        {
            m_log.error("Cannot connect plugin to self!");
            return false;
        }

        // Check for recursion
        if (plugin->pluginIsDescendant(this))
        {
            m_log.error("Cannot connect! Plugin recursion detected.");
            return false;
        }

        // Check if it already exists in the forward pipeline
        if (pluginIsDescendant(plugin))
            m_log.warning("Plugin already connected as descendant.");

        m_registered_plugins.push_back(plugin);

        return true;
    }

    ADD_TYPE(int);
    ADD_TYPE(std::string);
    ADD_TYPE(float);

protected:

    // Logger
    logger::Log m_log;

private:

    // Static boost generator
    static boost::uuids::random_generator m_uuid_gen;

    // UUID of plugin
    boost::uuids::uuid m_uuid;

    // Vector of registered analytics
    std::vector<PluginBase*> m_registered_plugins;
};



// EXAMPLE number CHILD CLASS
class NumberClass: public PluginBase
{
public:
  void receive(const routing::route_t& route, const int value) 
  {
     int output= transform(route, value);
     send(route, output);
  } 

  void receive(const routing::route_t& route, const float value) 
  {
     float output= transform(route, value);
     send(route, output);
  } 
};

// EXAMPLE std::string CHILD CLASS
class StringClass : public PluginBase
{
public:
  void receive(const routing::route_t& route, const std::string value) 
  {
     std::string output= transform(route, value);
     send(route, output);
  } 
};

// EXAMPLE print CHILD CLASS
class PrintClass : public PluginBase
{
public:
  void receive(const routing::route_t& route, const int value) 
  {
     std::cout << "Route " << route << " sent int = " << value << std::endl;
  } 

  void receive(const routing::route_t& route, const std::string value) 
  {
     std::cout << "Route " << route << " sent string = " << value << std::endl;
  } 
};

int main()
{
  NumberClass c1;
  StringClass c2;
  NumberClass c3;
  PrintClass c4;
  c1.connect(c4);
  c2.connect(c4);
  c3.connect(c4);

  c1.receive(1, 10);
  c2.receive(2, "hello");
  c3.receive(3, 3.1415);
};
```

Expected: 
Route 1 sent int = 10
Route 2 sent string = hello

Nothing is shown for the float 3.1415 because PrintClass never implemented the receive for float.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't even bother with that macro unless you have dozens of types you want to support that way. It confuses readers and IDEs, and only saves you time once.

Comment: The expectation is that there will be over 20 or 30 of these data types. I agree, it's a little confusing but I felt it certainly helped readability once I hit 10 types. These types are also a little more complex than just int/float/string. They are usually structs with timestamps, metadata and content using different types (float, vector of floats, strings, etc).

Comment: "This plugin pipeline would ideally be dynamic" If you were willing to bake the pipelines at compile time, then there are some template-based approaches that would be a LOT faster (and still look really nice at the pipeline definition point) than what you can get dynamically without going down the JIT rabbit hole.

Comment: I can get away without the JIT for the time being but eventually it will need to support variable configurations received via a websocket, push data through, then send it back out. Basically implemented a web server in C++ for realtime streaming and reprocessing... so I've already entered hell. Just trying to find the 9th layer.

Comment: Through object slicing, this should actually work. I have a small framework running with expected behavior that I'll post a little later. As long as pointers or references to the child classes are being stored in the registered plugins, it should resolve to the child's method. I'm wondering if the override isn't quite accurate. I know the posted code isn't quite in a compiling state, it was meant more as pseudo code. I'll mull over the idea of supporting both static and dynamic pipelines.